# Selecting a specific table in microsoft access 2007 with R code

Tags: r, ms-access, rodbc

I have an Access database with a couple of tables and I want to work in just one of them. I am using library `RODBC`. Let's say the table that I want to work it called `dtsample`. And my Access database is called `database.accdb`

Here is my code:

```
library(RODBC) 
dataconnect <- odbcConnectAccess2007("database.accdb")
data <- sqlQuery(dataconnect,"SELECT*dtsample columb1, columb2...)
```

but it does not work. How can I define the table in Access that I want to work with?

Comment: Your SQL statement is invalid. A valid statement would be `SELECT * FROM dtsample`. Also, can you tell us what error you are getting?

Comment: Best to paste the SELECT string into Access for easier testing (Design/Query, SQL Mode).

Comment: actually I kind a solve it with this code  Data <- sqlQuery(dataconnect,errors=FALSE, tableName="dtsample") but now I need to put some criterias. Like subset function. for example dtsample$Columb1 may include "a" and "b" I just want to take the ones with "a" and read it as a data frame in R. database is really huge so I need to subset it couple times before read it as a dataframe in R (I am really new to R sorry if this questions are so basic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is not really one, because you just got around learning about SELECT

```
data <- sqlQuery(dataconnect, "SELECT * from dtsample where Columb1 = 'a' or Columb1 ='b')
```

My suggestion you are not fluent in SQL: Use the query designer in Access, and when it works, get the SQL code generated (View:SQL) and paste it into R.

Comment: thank you. a  last question How can I fetch the data as a dataframe in R by using the query conditions?. (in other word when I use sqlfetch it takes the whole data I need to subset it by conditions)

Comment: Please specify more clearly what you mean. The "conditions" in the example above are given in the where clause.